# Makefile: runs successfully if I make object files separately

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

I am having two problems with makefile which I can not figure out myself. Hence, some help would be appreciated.

Also, I am new to linux and makefile. So, I would appreciate if someone can guide me to relevant resources for understanding these.

**Successful run:** I can run this makefile successfully, if I can do the following:
A) `$gcc -c tsnnls_test_DKU.c`
B) then, `$make`
3) I can call my function successfully.

**1) Unsuccessful run:** However, if I do comment in following in my make file

```
# Here is a simple Make Macro.
LINK_TARGET     = tsnnls_test_DKU
OBJS_LOC    = tsnnls_test_DKU.o
tsnnls_test_DKU.o: tsnnls_test_DKU.c
    gcc tsnnls_test_DKU.c
```

Then, then do `$make`, I get errors

```
dkumar@dkumar-Precision-WorkStation-T7500 ~/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls $ make
gcc tsnnls_test_DKU.c
/tmp/ccvbnByX.o: In function `lsqrwrapper':
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0x598): undefined reference to `alloc_lsqr_mem'
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0x6a8): undefined reference to `sparse_lsqr_mult'
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0x6c7): undefined reference to `lsqr'
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0x742): undefined reference to `free_lsqr_mem'
/tmp/ccvbnByX.o: In function `main':
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0x9cb): undefined reference to `taucs_construct_sorted_ccs_matrix'
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0xb15): undefined reference to `t_snnls_fallback'
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0xb66): undefined reference to `t_snnls'
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0xc92): undefined reference to `colvector_write_mat'
tsnnls_test_DKU.c:(.text+0xcce): undefined reference to `taucs_ccs_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tsnnls_test_DKU.o] Error 1
```

**2) Unsuccessful run:**  Also, if I comment out "`clean: ..`" part in makefile, it just cleans up and does not make when I try:

A) `$gcc -c tsnnls_test_DKU.c`
B) then, `$make`

then, I get the **following output**:

```
dkumar@dkumar-Precision-WorkStation-T7500 ~/libtsnnls-2.3.3/tsnnls $ make
rm -f tsnnls_test_DKU   
echo Clean done
Clean done
```

Here is my makefile

```
# A sample Makefile

# Here is a simple Make Macro.
LINK_TARGET     = tsnnls_test_DKU
OBJS_LOC    = tsnnls_test_DKU.o
#tsnnls_test_DKU.o: tsnnls_test_DKU.c
#   gcc tsnnls_test_DKU.c

# Here is a Make Macro that uses the backslash to extend to multiple lines.
OBJS =  libtsnnls_la-taucs_malloc.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_order.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_ops.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_vec_base.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_complex.o libtsnnls_la-colamd.o \
    libtsnnls_la-amdbar.o libtsnnls_la-amdexa.o \
    libtsnnls_la-amdtru.o libtsnnls_la-genmmd.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_timer.o libtsnnls_la-taucs_sn_llt.o \
    libtsnnls_la-taucs_ccs_base.o libtsnnls_la-tlsqr.o \
    libtsnnls_la-tsnnls.o libtsnnls_la-lsqr.o   \
    $(OBJS_LOC)

REBUILDABLES = $(LINK_TARGET) 


##DK COMMENTED OUT THE CLEANING PART 
#clean : 
#   rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)   
#   echo Clean done

all : $(LINK_TARGET)
    echo All done

#Inclusion of all libraries
RANLIB = ranlib
STATICLIB= /usr/local/lib/taucs_full/lib/linux/libtaucs.a 

tsnnls_test_LDADD = $(LDADD)
LIBS = -largtable2 -llapack -lblas -lquadmath -lm

$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)   $(tsnnls_test_LDADD) $(LIBS)  $(STATICLIB)
    gcc -g -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the actual (complete and unedited) output from `make`, including the commands it tries to run?

Comment: In your successful compile, you are using the `-c` option which doesn't attempt to link. In your first unsuccessful make file, you omitted the `-c`, and the error is because it can't find the symbol it's trying to link to. If you leave out the `-c` on your first attempt, it would also generate an error. Your comments on your second makefile issue aren't making sense to me. You are saying that if you *comment out* (make into a comment) the *clean* target lines, then running the make will do a clean?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I updated the actual output from make for unsuccessful run-1.

Comment: @lurker Thanks. If I use the same **-C** option in makefile, then it does not proceed beyond that line and I had to comment out and recompile.

Comment: You don't link with anything, so anything in external libraries/object files will not be found.

Comment: @GarimaSingh indeed. But that's what you did on your command line. The makefile isn't the problem. The problem is, as Joachim says, you need to include linkage to the appropriate libraries if you leave off `-c`.

Comment: Answer to question 2 is, iiuc, that the first target in a makefile is the default target which will be built if no target is given as a make command line parameter. If you comment the *clean* target in it is the default (and only one) which will be built. Typically "all" or at least the executable will be the default target, i.e. must be first.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thanks, it worked. So, I should run "make all" to make and "make clean" to clean.

Comment: As I said, the usual standard (what a user would expect) is to have *all:* be the first target so that a bare `make` would build *all*.